# How can i run a javascript just one time in phtml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, customer

I have a GTM script for login in `Magento_Customer/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml`

```
<script>
dataLayer.push({
    'events':{
        'event':'login',
        'category':'login',
        'action':'login',
        'label': <?php echo "'" . $block->getCustomer()->getId() . "'" ?>

    },
    'user':{
        'visitorLoginState':'logged in'
    }


 });
</script>
```

I want this script to run just one time, when a user is logged in.
Now if a refresh the browser the script run again.

Does anyone know how can i run this script just one time?

A know i can use registry, but i am in a phtml.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use customer session variable.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if(!$customerSession->getIsScriptRun()){
     ....Your Code....
     $customerSession->setIsScriptRun(true);
}
```

Now to clear customer session after a customer logs out,
You need to create an `observer` 
Create a file `etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_logout"> <!-- use one of the events above -->
        <observer name="[namespace]_[module]" instance="[Namespace]\[Module]\Observer\Logout" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create observer file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Observer/Logout.php` and add below code.

```
<?php 
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Observer;

class Logout implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface 
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $customerSession->unsIsScriptRun();
    }
}
```

Comment: what this ->getIsScriptRun()) means?

Comment: It is a session variable. First time it will not be set and will allow the script to run. then we have set value for the session variable using `$customerSession->setIsScriptRun(true);` so the condition `if(!$customerSession->getIsScriptRun())` will not be true and the script will not run again.

Comment: it works for the firs time. but if a try to login with another user the script it's not run again. can i do something to run when i logged in with another user?

Comment: You mean when you logged out from one user and logged in with another, at that time the script is not working?

Comment: yes. it's not working

Comment: It is using customer session, so it should get clear when you log out.

Comment: @AlinLupoiu, please check updated code.